# Guaranteed way to correctly get the contents of www.bing.com/

Tags: java, bing, correctness

I have been working on a program that gets the contents of www.bing.com and saves it to a file, but out of the two ways I have tried one using sockets, and the other using HtmlUnit neither shows the contents 100% correct when I open the file.  I know there are other options out there, but I looking for one that is guaranteed to get the contents of www.bing.com/ correctly.  I would therefore appreciate it if someone could point me to a means of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 4):

The differences you see are likely due to the web server providing different content to different browsers based on the user agent string and other request headers.

Try setting the `User-Agent` header in your socket and HtmlUnit strategies to the one you are comparing against and see if the result is as expected.  Moreover, you will likely have to replicate the request headers exactly as they are sent by your target browser.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by User-Agent or what exactly you are saying to do.

Comment: From Wikipedia: When software agent operates in a network protocol, it often identifies itself, its application type, OS, software vendor, or software revision, by submitting a characteristic identification string to its operating peer. In HTTP, SIP, and SMTP/NNTP protocols, this identification is transmitted in a header field User-Agent. Bots, such as Web crawlers, often also include a URL and/or e-mail address so that the Webmaster can contact the operator of the bot.
e.g.: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405

Answer (score 0):

What is "incorrect" about what is returned? Keep in mind, Bing is probably generating some of the content via JavaScript; your client will need to make additional requests to retrieve the JavaScript files, run the JavaScript, etc.

Comment: When I use HtmlUnit it comes out mostly correct except for this part at the bottom gets cut off and  the bullet symbols do not show up as bullets                                                                                                     Guaranteed giggles   Family Fun    Popular Now
Got a couple minutes? Games, crafts, tips, and more              Alabama vs. LSU •   Broncos vs.Steelers • Johnny Deep • Amir Mirzaei Hekmati

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`URL.openConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) to create a [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) and call [`URLConnection.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream%28%29). You can read the InputStream contents and write it to a file.

If you need to override the User-Agent because the server is using it to serve different content you can do so by first setting the `http.agent` system property to empty string.

```
/* Somewhere in your code before you make requests */
System.setProperty("http.agent", "");
```

or using `-Dhttp.agent=` on your java command line

and then setting the User-Agent to something useful on the connection before you get the InputStream.

```
URLConnection conn = ... //Create your URL connection as described above.
String userAgent = ... //Some user-agent string here.
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
```